# How can I get the table I need?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with grouping my data.

This is a piece of my dataset, with a few reviews of hospitals and dentists and the year and month of these reviews:

**Respondent    Id nr   Name   score    year    month**
1             6665   Hospital 7,0      2020      1
2              6668       Dentist        5,5    2020     1
3              6665       Hospital 6,8    2020       2
4           6668    Dentist   5,7    2019   12

When I use this script:

```
df[['idnumber', 'score', 'respondents' , 'year', 'month',]].groupby('Id nr').agg({'score': 'mean', 'respondents': 'count'}).reset_index()
```

I get the first table that I need:

**Id nr  Score  Respondent**
6665   6,9   2
6668   5,6   2

But now I also want to include 2 extra variabels in the table:
    1. The column 'Name'. What piece of code can I use here instead of 'mean' or 'count'? 
    2. Then I want to know how many reviews there are in each month of the year.

How can I change the script so I get the table below?

**Id nr Score Respondent Name  2019 - 12 2020 - 1 2020 - 2**
6665 6,9     2    Hospital    
 0     1    1
6668 5,6     2    Dentist   1     1    0

Comment: how are you able to get the mean for the Score column? It's in a non-numeric format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by concatenating your two date columns

```
df['date'] = df['year'].astype(str) + "-" + df['month'].astype(str)
```

then  performing your pandas groupby operations/merges and get_dummies to expand your date column values before grouping it again to get your desired output. I'm assuming the Score Column was meant to have float values.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Id nr','Name']).agg({'Respondent':'count', 'Score':'mean'}).reset_index()
df2 = pd.merge(df2, df[['Id nr', 'Name','date']], on=['Id nr', 'Name'], how='left')
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df2, columns =['date'])
df2 = df2.groupby(['Id nr','Name','Respondent','Score']).agg(sum).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   Id nr    Name    Respondent  Score   date_2019-12   date_2020-1  date_2020-2
0   6665    Hospital    2        6.9       0                  1         1
1   6668    Dentist     2        5.6       1                  1         0
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you have named differently your columns df example - code.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'Resp':[1,2,3,4],
    'Id_nr':[6665,6668,6665,6668],
    'Name':['Hospital','Dentist','Hospital','Dentist'],
    'score':[7.0,5.5,6.8,5.7],
    'year':[2020,2020,2020,2019],
    'month':[1,1,2,12]
})
df_1=df
df_1['Y-M'] = df_1['year'].astype(str) +' - '+ df_1['month'].astype(str)
df_1 = df_1[['Y-M',"Name",'year']].pivot(index='Name',columns='Y-M')
df_1 = df_1.notnull().astype('int')
df = df.groupby(['Id_nr','Name']).agg({'score': 'mean', 'Resp': 'count'}).reset_index()
print(df)

   Id_nr      Name  Resp  score
0   6665  Hospital     2    6.9
1   6668   Dentist     2    5.6

print(df_1)
              year                  
Y-M      2019 - 12 2020 - 1 2020 - 2
Name                                
Dentist          1        1        0
Hospital         0        1        1


df= df.merge(df_1,on="Name")
print(df)
   Id_nr      Name  Resp  score  (year, 2019 - 12)  (year, 2020 - 1)  (year, 2020 - 2)
0   6665  Hospital     2    6.9                  0                 1                 1
1   6668   Dentist     2    5.6                  1                 1                 0
```